# reverseproxy apache to nginx for flask app

Tags: python, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have a flask app running with gunicorn on port `127.0.0.1:5000`.

This server has a bunch of sites running on apache, I want to use nginx for my flask app.

So I have the nginx config file looking like this and listens on port `81`.

```
server {
    listen 81;

    server_name ip;
    root /var/www/html/example;

    access_log /var/www/html/example/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/example/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location /static/ { }

    location /uploads/ { }
}
```

So far so good, if i go to `<ip>:81` i will se the site running. But now i want to point it to my domain `example.com` so I simply change `server_name ip;` to `server_name example.com`. This will obviously not work because I have apache as well. So I want to reverseproxy apache to my nginx backend. So I put this in my config file for apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:81/
</VirtualHost>
```

But somehwere I am missing something, where am I failing this?

Comment: Add this also `RequestHeader set Host "example.com"`

Comment: @TarunLalwani in my apache config? it didn't solve my problem :/

Comment: Remove `server_name` from your nginx config all together

Comment: But does it look accurate what I am doing? Why would I want to remove `server_name` from nginx?

Comment: Because you are nginx is not directly facing client, it is just facing apache